# Align two text inputs side by side and touching

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap3, this is pretty close to what I'm trying to do

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"> </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City"/>
</div>
```

which looks like

[image]

but I'm really going for something more like

[image: postalcode city combo input]

Comment: what are you using this `<span class="input-group-addon"> </span>` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `css` class and it will solve your problem

```
.input-group-addon {
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background: #FFF;
}
```

There are other ways to do this but this is the simplest one.

Comment: I added `border: 0;background: #FFFFFF;` to make it disappear completely. But this worked for me.  thanks :)